# Changing the foreground of button text and image on mouse over

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a button defined as follows:

```
<Button x:Name="ContactLink" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="223" Style="{StaticResource HyperlinkButton}" Click="ContactLink_Clicked">
    <WrapPanel>
        <Rectangle Width="15" Height="15">
             <Rectangle.Fill>
                 <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_new_window}" />
             </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <TextBlock Margin="5 0 0 0" FontWeight="SemiBold" Text="GET IN TOUCH" />
     </WrapPanel>
</Button>
```

As the title says, I would like to define a style which changes the foreground of TextBlock and of the VisualBrush. So far, I have the following style, which doesn't work. It changes the foreground of the textblock and the definition of the BlackBrush resource.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="HyperlinkButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
         <WrapPanel>
             <TextBlock Cursor="Hand">
                  <ContentPresenter />
             </TextBlock>
         </WrapPanel>
         <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
             <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                 <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="#0071bc" />
             </Trigger>
         </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="HyperlinkButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource HyperlinkButtonTemplate}" />
    </Style>
 </ResourceDictionary>
```

Any help on getting it to work would be very much appreciated.

Comment: your visual brush has vector image ?

Comment: Yes. It has a vector image, as it can be found here: http://modernuiicons.com

Comment: to be more clear you want to change the color of your vector image based on foreground color?

Comment: Yes, I want to change the color of the vector image and of the text when the user hovers with the mouse over the button control. The SVG image makes use of a resource named "BlackBrush" to draw itself.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the SolidColorBrush you defined inside the trigger

```
<Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="#0071bc" />
 </Trigger>
```

Comment: I modified the style as you suggested, but the color still doesn't change.

Comment: Worked for me! Foreground does change on mouseover

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late, but I had the same issue and managed to solve it.
Just set name property of the TextBlock then you can refer to that name in the trigger.

```
<TextBlock Cursor="Hand" Name="MyTextBlock">
          <ContentPresenter />
</TextBlock>

<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
             <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="MyTextBlock" Property="Foreground" Value="#0071bc"/>
             </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```